# using structures in GCC and getting errors 

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, struct

The same code ran in TURBO C.

```
    struct details
    {
      char name[20];
      int year;
      float price;
    }my_str;

    details book1[10];
```

This error is produced. How can this be fixed?

```
ram.c: In function ‘main’:
ram.c:11:1: error: ‘details’ undeclared (first use in this function)
ram.c:11:1: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Comment: the reason you get the error is that in C++ it is allowed to write like you did above but in C not. My guess is that Borland had added that as an extension Turbo C as they were moving towards C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to fix this:

Change second line to this:

```
struct details book1[10];
```

Or you can change the declaration to:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[20];
    int year;
    float price;
} details;
```

C is slightly different from C++, so you can't declare structs quite the same way.

Answer (score 3):

```
details book1[10];
```

needs to be ...

```
struct details book1[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the structure variable declaration like this:

```
struct details book1[10];
```

This is because the `details` is not `typedef`ed, and therefore you cannt use it like a user defined type, and therefore you need to use the `struct` keyword.

Note that, in your above definition `my_str` is a variable (allocated object) of type `struct details`

You can also do:

```
typedef struct details
{
  char name[20];
  int year;
  float price;
} my_str;
```

And then do:

```
my_str book1[10];
```

This is same as above. Here note that, the `my_str` is not a variable (object) but the typename which you have defined with the `typedef` keyword. After this point the compiler would know that you are using the `my_str` as a new user defined type name for the composite structure data type you have created, and therefore you can use `my_str` directly instead of using `struct details`

Answer (score 0):

This is a a bit more correct in terms of C:

```
typedef struct _detailstype
{
  char name[20];
  int year;
  float price;
} details;


details book1[10];
```